# How to add new position to search path

Tags: r

I would like to how to add new custom position to search path. How to source functions from file to this new position rather than to global environment?

Comment: See the example in `?sys.source`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich this is answer to my second question.

Answer (score 2):

The `attach` function will attach data frames, lists, environments, and saved images to the search path.  Many of the functions for reading in objects or evaluating objects will let you specify an environment to place the results in.

One simple option is to have all the objects in your global environment and use the 'save' function to save them.  Then in a new R session you can use `attach` with the file that you saved and everything is in the search path but not in the global environment.

You can also create a new environment and attach that, then load things into that environment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @JoshuaUlrich suggestion:

```
sys.source(file_name, env=attach(NULL, name = "file_env"))
```